# Postgresql Tutorial Error 1: pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive Error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to learn PostgreSQL tutorial and I keep coming to their error. 
Have no idea how to fix it.

It failed with error code 1

```
Restoring backup on the server 'PostgreSQL 10 (x86) (localhost:5432)'...
Running command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_restore.exe --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "dvdrental" --verbose "C:\\Users\\tbui106\\Desktop\\_SQL\\DVDREN~1.TAR"

pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

Can someone help? Been on this for hours!

Comment: How was `DVDREN~1.TAR` created?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: it's probably this one here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

Comment: Maybe your download got corrupted, because that should work. Try to download it again. Or did you save the `.zip` download from [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/) and renamed it to `.tar`? You need to first extract the .tar from the .zip